# Why my PWA Android doesn't ask notification permission when first running?

Tags: android, google-chrome, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA and it can be downloaded from Google Play Store.
The problem is, the Android app of my PWA installed from Play Store doesn't ask the user's notification permission(which is poped up with Chrome prompt) when it is run first time after installation.
However if I visit that PWA service via Chrome browser(both of Android or PC) for the first time, the notification permission request is shown correctly.
Why only standalone version PWA Android doesn't ask the notification permission?
Although I have found the way how to turn the notification on of the standalone PWA Android via Chrome setting(rf: [Turning on notification permission on PWA after permission was denied in app settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77209026/turning-on-notification-permission-on-pwa-after-permission-was-denied-in-app-set)), but I want provide higher user experiences of notification setting just like the case of Chrome browser, not the manual one.

Anyone who has trouble like mine?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.